# Got OutOfMemoryError after update Android Gradle Plugin to 3.6.1 from 3.5.3 when run unit test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After update to use Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.1 from 3.5.3, our unit test keeps getting OutOfMemoryError exception randomly.

These are the crash logs:

```html
 Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception was raised by workers:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
  at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:108)
  at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:118)
  at kotlin.io.CloseableKt.closeFinally(Closeable.kt:53)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.doFullTaskAction(GenerateLibraryRFileTask.kt:120)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:107)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.access$handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:64)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:73)
```

As my investigation. AGP 3.6.x changed the way to generate the R file. And the crash happens in this line of code: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/res/GenerateLibraryRFileTask.kt#120

So far, what I have tried are:

1. Try to play with some gradle flags. But so far, there is no luck.

   - android.enableGradleWorkers=true/false
   - kapt.use.worker.api=true/false
   - kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project=true/false
   - android.useCompileClasspathLibraryRClasses=false
2. Play around with some testOptions flags (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html), for example forkEvery, maxParallelForks. But I am not sure it would help, because the failure happens on the building phrase.

   I am trying to get the heapdump but it's kind of difficult because the OOM happens randomly.

   My setup:

   - Gradle version: 6.2.2
   - Android Gradle Plugin: 3.6.1
   - Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     And I run the unit test by the command-line tool. It should not be related to AS.

It will be very appreciated if anyone of you would suggest any solution or direction to investigate

Answer (score 1):

Just for your info. I have to fire an issue too google here 
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/151460310